# How do I extract certain rows from a list based on a string of characters

Tags: r, list, parsing

I have a string of characters:x

```
"A" "B" "C"
```

Also a list of two variables:y

```
m A
n B
n D
q D
m B
```

How can I get a subset of y based on x like this:

```
m A
n B
m B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to subset y.

```
y[y$b %in% x,]
#  a b
#1 m A
#2 n B
#5 m B
```

Data:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
y <- data.frame(a=c("m", "n", "n", "q", "m"), b=c("A", "B", "D", "D", "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`, if you are using a data.frame

```r
df <- read_table2("x1 x2
m A
n B
n D
q D
s B")
df %>% filter(x2 == "A" | x2 == "B")
```